# Add text to a column in a listview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a table with two columns, and a button that when I click add text to two columns, the code I use for that is this:

```
    listView1.Items.Add("hi 1");
    listView1.Columns.Add("hi 2"); // ERROR
```

the issue is that the second column is not complete but if done right the first everything.

anyone can help me?

Comment: I have read your question twice and didn't understand anything. What do you mean by *clicking add text to two columns*? What is *first everything*? What is *done right*? What is *not complete column*? Also you haven't specified error which you have

Comment: sorry for my English because I'm Spanish, I'm trying to do is simply: add items to a table that has two columns

Comment: You want probably to set also the View property of the ListView to Details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with array of subitems with item for each column in your ListView. If you have two columns:

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "hi", "2" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ListView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can layout the items it contains differently. The layout that has also a Column header is the Details layout. It can be set using the [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the ListView class.

Also you need **first** to add the columns and **then** add the items, so that the control knows how and where to put the items.

An example:

```
    var lv = new ListView();
    // set layout with column headers
    lv.View = View.Details;
    // add one column
    lv.Columns.Add("A");
    // add two items to column A
    lv.Items.Add("Item 1");
    lv.Items.Add("Item 2");
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Bear in mind not to add the columns every time the button is clicked, but only once.

If you have more than one column, then every column after the first one, should be added as a [SubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of currently added [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) item:

```
    // add two column
    lv.Columns.Add("A");
    lv.Columns.Add("B");
    // add one item to column A and B
    var lvi = lv.Items.Add("Item 1");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("SubItem 1");
    // add once again one row to column A and B
    lvi = lv.Items.Add("Item 2");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("SubItem 2");
```

The form looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this is what I do not understand, the listview and put it in detail and created from the toolbox, and all the answers I seek are the same as your answer, I can not use the table name listView1 already believed from the menu tools?

Answer (score 0):

```
MyList.ForEach(name => listView1.Columns.Add(name));
```

Try this or

```
        ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
        header.Text = "gkgag";
        header.Width = 100;
        header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        listView1.Columns.Add(header);
```